# Using the forumula for Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability

I just want to make sure I'm doing this right.

The formula we were given was

[image]

> A company is suffering from severe quality control problems, resulting
> in 20% of its products being defective. If five products are randomly
> chosen, what is the probability that:
>
> i.    3 are faulty

i) $C(5,3) \times (0.2)^3 \times (0.2)^2$

Is this correct?

I put the successes k as the number of faulty units which is 3. Then q and p as 0.2

I feel like this is wrong but I'm getting confused as to what values I use.

Comment: Check again your value for $q$

Comment: oh thanks i missed that, q is supposed to be 0.8.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.